# mongo update not working inside async eachseries

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I was using async eachSeries to iterate through an array and update a collection

```
coll.find().toArray(function (err, doc) {
    async.eachSeries(doc,
        function (obj, cb) {
            var arrayLength = headerval.length;
            var total = 0;
            for (var j = 0; j < arrayLength; j++) {
                var val = headerval[j];
                total += obj[val];

            }
            console.log(total)
            obj[newcolumn] = total;
            var oId = obj['_id']
            delete obj['_id']
            coll.update({
                _id: oId
            }, {
                $set: obj
            }, {
                upsert: true,
                multi: true
            }, function (err, result) {
                console.log(result)
                cb(err);
            });
        },
        function (err) {

        }
    );
});
```

`console.log(total)` and `console.log(obj)` are printing expected results.

The `console.log(result)` is printing `1` if I print `result` it prints null. But the collection is not getting updated.

`doc` is the result of a mongo find.
`headerVal` consists of a list of keys available in `doc`

Comment: As you are doing the update on ID. I think only one document could be found and updated as the find would be returning only one document before update.

Comment: @Jayram: Yes true. But on each of those one document should be updated right? But here only one is updated. Even though I get `total` and `obj` and `oId` different on each case

Comment: Is doc a cursor? If it is, fetching the actual document from a cursor item is an async operation. Try using the native cursor iterator, that might be your problem. http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html

Comment: @joao doc is a result of another find query `coll.find().toArray(function (err, doc) {  `

Comment: It isn't a cursor then since you used toArray. In the update options add also safe : true. {upsert:true, multi:true, safe:true} - if you don't do this, the callback maybe called before the update takes place.

Comment: @joao Still I'm having the same issue